# jQuery: `:eq(i) ` Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign 10 div class `hi` with different height.

I know I can do it this way.

```
$(".hi:eq(0)").css("height",n[0]);
$(".hi:eq(1)").css("height",n[1]);
$(".hi:eq(2)").css("height",n[2]);
   ..........
$(".hi:eq(9)").css("height",n[9]);
```

However, when I try generating them by using a `for` loop it doesn't work.

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){

$(".hi:eq(i)").css("height",n[i]);

}
```

Neither does this.

```
var i=0;
$(".hi:eq(i)").css("height",n[i]);
```

Something must be wrong with `:eq(i)`.

Comment: what does left have to do with height?  (and i can't be within the string as posted below)

Comment: @FiveTools For the _left_ blame it on my dyslexia.

Comment: You have to concat 'i' with .hi:eq like:
$(".hi:eq(" + i + ")").css("height",n[i]);

Comment: @RicardoLohmann Yeah thanks but I will go with `slice(0,10)` since `eq(i)` is not really a standard selector.

Comment: @ArchJ I think it's better too. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is that JavaScript doesn't have string interpolation.

But do it like this instead...

```
$(".hi").slice(0,10)
        .css('height', function(i) { 
            return n[i]; 
        });
```

This is *far* more efficient than repeating your DOM selection with a non-standard selector.

- `.slice(0,10)` will give you the first 10 elements
- `.css()` with a function passed as the second argument will assign the return value to the `height` css property of the current element in the iteration. The index of the current iteration is represented by the `i` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! But shouldn't it be `slice(0,9)`? Since I've got 10 elements instead of 11.

Comment: @ArchJ: If there are only 10 elements, you don't need `.slice()` at all, but otherwise, no. The second argument represents the *non-inclusive* stopping point, so `0,10` will give you indices `0-9` inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

`i` can't be within the string. You probably want this:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    $(".hi:eq(" + i + ")").css("left", n[i]);
}
```